# make a button display an element each time its pressed

Tags: swift, swift5

I am new to Swift, and I am trying to make a basic question answer app. I want to set up the question button so that whenever I press it, it displays one question, and if I press it again, it shows another question. I have a separate button that will show the answer but I need to connect to which ever question is being asked. How do I do this?

Here is what I have so far, it just asks the question at random, but I want to be able to ask all the questions, not just whatever it picks, I am not sure how to do that though.

```swift
    @IBAction func question(_ sender: Any) {
        let questions = ["What is your name?", "What is your favourite colour?",
            "What is your favourite movie?", "What is your major?"]
        let randomQuestion = questions.randomElement()
        qLabel.text = randomQuestion
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question, please?

Comment: how do i make a button that displays a different question each time i press the button, and how do i attach that to an answer button as well

Comment: That's two questions. Please try to confine yourself to one question, and please make it specific. How to "attach that to an answer button" is very broad (and not entirely clear). Without asking us to write your whole app for you, do ask us to help with a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var index = 0 // add a current index of the shown question
let questions = ["What is your name?", "What is your favourite colour?",
        "What is your favourite movie?", "What is your major?"]
@IBAction func question(_ sender: Any) {  
    if index < questions.count {  
      qLabel.text = questions[index] 
      index += 1
    }
    else { 
      // end of questions 
   }
   
}
```